# Plot probability of detection against number of surveys using 'unmarked' package

Tags: r, detection, unmarked-package

I am trying to plot the probability of detection vs number of surveys following an eradication attempt, to produce plots like the below:

[image]

From the following publication:
https://dspace.lib.hawaii.edu/server/api/core/bitstreams/d5c5c776-afbe-4762-b282-e73a72fe6b78/content

I have imported a very simple dataset in the following format:

```
Trap Time1 Time2 Time3
   1     1     0     0
   2     0     0     0
   3     1     0     0
   4     1     0     0 ...
```

I do not want to include any covariates, just probability with 95% confidence intervals as it changes with subsequent survey events. So far I have the following code but cannot figure out how to get plots like the above:

```
y<-data[2:4]
blgr<-unmarkedFrameOccu(y=y)
fm1<-occu(~1 ~1, blgr)
fm1
```

Any assistance would be appreciated.